# Passing Inputs to command line prompt

Tags: node.js, command-line, child-process

Hi am trying to execute a shell command with spawn child process , which has multiple prompt question to be answered

I am able to initiate the command...but not able to answer the prompt question

i have tried multiple solutions but getting stuck on on the prompt input...

Here is the Code

```
var cmd2 = cd C:\\**\\**\\Desktop\\RASA_TEST & C:\\**\\**\\Scripts\\activate & SET              
PYTHONIOENCODING='utf8' & rasa init

      const lsProcess = spawn(cmd2, [] , {
          // shell: true,
          // detached: false,
          // windowsHide: true,
          //  stdio: ['pipe', process.stdout, process.stderr]
          stdio: 'inherit',
          shell: true
       });

   
      lsProcess.stdin.on('data', function(data) {`your text`
         console.log('stdout: ' + data);
         // if(data?.inculdes('default Directory')){
         //     console.log("there it is")
         // }
      });
```

Error:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'on')

Could any one help please